# Cannot iterate on a non-copyable container returned by a function

Tags: boost, boost-foreach

I'm not sure of the title, because I'm not sure the issue comes from the "copyablility" of my container.
I tryied quite everything but I can't get rid of this error.

Here is a simplified version of my code (please do not challenge the class design, I really would like to keep the end-used syntax in the BOOST_FOREACH):

```
template <typename T>
class MyContainer
{
public:
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    MyContainer(std::vector<T>& vec, boost::mutex& mutex) :
        m_vector(vec),
        m_lock(mutex)
    {
    }

    iterator begin() { return m_vector.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return m_vector.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return m_vector.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return m_vector.end(); }


private:
    std::vector<T>& m_vector;
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> m_lock;
};

template <typename T>
struct GetContainer
{
    GetContainer(std::vector<T>& vec, boost::mutex& mutex) :
        m_vector(vec),
        m_mutex(mutex)
    {
    }

    MyContainer<T> Get()
    {
        return MyContainer<T>(m_vector, m_mutex);
    }

    std::vector<T>& m_vector;
    boost::mutex& m_mutex;
};



int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    boost::mutex m;

    GetContainer<int> getter(v, m);

    BOOST_FOREACH(int i, getter.Get())
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains about not having a copy constructor for MyContainer::MyContainer(const MyContainer&).
I also have :
error: no matching function for call to ‘MyContainer::MyContainer(boost::foreach_detail_::rvalue_probe >::value_type)’

I follow the extensibility tips:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/foreach/extensibility.html#foreach.extensibility.making__literal_boost_foreach__literal__work_with_non_copyable_sequence_types

But, making

```
MyContainer<T> : private boost::noncopyable
```

doesn't solve the issue.
Nor defining the function

```
boost_foreach_is_noncopyable
```

or specializing the template struct

```
is_noncopyable
```

for MyContainer (in fact, how would I specialize this template for a template type ?)

**Last "tip"**:
If I remove the mutex and the lock from everywhere (I just pass the vector to GetContainer and to MyContainer), it works.
But it doesn't work if I make

```
MyContainer<T> : private boost::noncopyable
```

(I expected it should, so I'm not sure my problem is with BOOST_FOREACH, but maybe because I return a copy of MyContainer with my getter ?)

I thank you if you read me until here, and thanks in advance for help.

Comment: The copy is done inside BOOST_FOREACH. The problem is lack of move semantics AFAICT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a limitation of BOOST_FOREACH with move-only types. I didn't find a way around it¹ (except for the - ugly - obvious approach to put the `lock_guard` in a `shared_ptr`).

You didn't specify a c++03 requirement, though, so you can make it work without BOOST_FOREACH by replacing `lock_guard` with `unique_lock`.

Here's my take on things in c++11 (note how generic it is):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/802e08a8bccbf81f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/range.hpp>

namespace detail {
    template <typename R, typename M>
    struct RangeLock {
        RangeLock(R&r, M& m) : _r(r), _l(m) {}
        RangeLock(RangeLock&&) = default;

        using iterator = typename boost::range_iterator<R>::type;
        iterator begin() { using std::begin; return begin(_r); }
        iterator end  () { using std::end;   return end  (_r); }

        using const_iterator = typename boost::range_iterator<R const>::type;
        const_iterator begin() const { using std::begin; return begin(_r); }
        const_iterator end  () const { using std::end;   return end  (_r); }

     private:
        R& _r;
        boost::unique_lock<M> _l;
    };
}

template <typename R, typename M>
    detail::RangeLock<R,M> make_range_lock(R& r, M& mx) { return {r,mx}; }
template <typename R, typename M>
    detail::RangeLock<R const,M> make_range_lock(R const& r, M& mx) { return {r,mx}; }

#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main() {

    boost::mutex mx;

    std::vector<int> const vec { 1, 2 };
    std::map<int, std::string> const map { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" } };

    for(int i : make_range_lock(vec, mx))
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

    for(auto& p : make_range_lock(map, mx))
        std::cout << p.second << std::endl;

    for(auto& p : make_range_lock(boost::make_iterator_range(map.equal_range(1)), mx))
        std::cout << p.second << std::endl;

}
```

Prints

```
1
2
one
two
one
```

---

¹ not even using all the approaches from [Using BOOST_FOREACH with a constant intrusive list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836399/using-boost-foreach-with-a-constant-intrusive-list/10837672#10837672)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok no way with BOOST_FOREACH.
In my case I cant' use c++11, and even if, I'll finally put the lock in a shared_ptr. It's quite que ugly technical workaround, but for my team I want to keep the simple syntax of foreach.

Answer (score 0):

I post my answer if it can help...

**With C++03**, I finally provide a copy constructor to be able to use the class with BOOST_FOREACH.
So the issue is moved to another topic: make the class copied in a logic and suitable way.

In my case, I "share the lock and the vector", the user shouldn't use this copy itself if he doesn't want to do bugs, but in BOOST_FOREACH it's okay:

- I change the mutex to a recursive_mutex
- I change the lock to an unique_lock
  and:

  ```
  MyContainer(const MyContainer& other) :
                              m_vector(other.vec),
                              m_lock(*other.m_lock.mutex())
  {
  }
  ```

**With C++11**

Thanks to Chris Glover on the boost mailling list, a C++11 solution:

> You can't do what you are trying to do in C++03.  To accomplish it, you 
>   need C++11 move semantics to be able to move the MyContainer out of the Get 
>   function. Even without using BOOST_FOREACH, the following code fails;
>
> ```
> GetContainer<int> getter(v, m); 
> MyContainer<int> c = getter.Get(); // <-- Error.
> ```
>
> Here's an example with the necessary changes; I changed the scoped_lock to 
>   a unique_lock and added a move constructor.
>
> ```
> template <typename T> 
> class MyContainer 
> { 
> public: 
> [...]
>     MyContainer(MyContainer&& other) 
>         : m_vector(other.m_vector) 
>     { 
>         m_lock = std::move(other.m_lock); 
>         other.m_vector = nullptr; 
>     }
> ```

Comment: Erm. I think I supplied exactly the same fix for C++11 in my answer (_"so you can make it work without BOOST_FOREACH by replacing `lock_guard` with `unique_lock`._"). Changing the mutex to be recursive is a non-trivial change and invites a slew of problems associated with recursive mutexes. I'd favour the `shared_ptr<lock>` here

Comment: @sehe you're right. I was just answering again for the move semantic tip. And for the usage **with** BOOST_FOREACH.
But you're answer is the accepted one with +1 from me ;-)